# Fetching array of NSManagedObjects by objectID returns empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to perform a fetch to retrieve managed objects from the context using an array of object IDs I gathered from a separate context. However, the fetch comes back with an empty array.

From the "Retrieving Specific Objects" section of the "Core Data Programming Guide"
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1):

> If your application uses multiple contexts and you want to test whether an object has been deleted from a persistent store, you can create a fetch request with a predicate of the form self == %@. The object you pass in as the variable can be either a managed object or a managed object ID..."
>
> If you need to test for the existence of several objects, it is more efficient to use the IN operator than it is to execute multiple fetches for individual objects, for example:
>
> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@",
>                                                 arrayOfManagedObjectIDs];

While this is talking about testing for object deletion, I presumed if the objects are not deleted then the results array is not empty, and will contain the actual NSManagedObjects. However, when I execute this code:

```
- (NSArray *)managedObjectsOfEntityName:(NSString *)entityName fromObjectIDs:(NSArray *)objectIDs managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", objectIDs];

    __autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;

    NSManagedObjectID *testID = objectIDs[0];
    NSManagedObject *obj = [managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:testID error:&error];
    if (!obj)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch. Error: %@", error);
    }

    error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!results)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch. Error: %@", error);
    }

    return results;
}
```

The `results` array is non-nil and empty, while `obj` is properly populated.

I've added the explicit call to `existingObjectWithID:` as a sanity check, and it comes back with the expected object, without error.

Here's the debugger output for the pertinent variables:

```
(lldb) po entityName
Foo

(lldb) po objectIDs
<__NSArrayI 0x1170d4950>(
0xd0000000055c0082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p343>,
0xd000000008e80082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p570>,
0xd000000008840082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p545>,
0xd000000006040082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p385>,
0xd000000007740082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p477>,
0xd000000008280082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p522>,
0xd000000008e40082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p569>
)

(lldb) po request
<NSFetchRequest: 0x10f338840> (entity: Foo; predicate: (SELF IN {
0xd0000000055c0082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p343>,
0xd000000008e80082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p570>,
0xd000000008840082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p545>,
0xd000000006040082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p385>,
0xd000000007740082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p477>,
0xd000000008280082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p522>,
0xd000000008e40082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p569>});
sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

(lldb) po request.predicate
SELF IN {
0xd0000000055c0082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p343>,
0xd000000008e80082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p570>,
0xd000000008840082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p545>,
0xd000000006040082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p385>,
0xd000000007740082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p477>,
0xd000000008280082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p522>,
0xd000000008e40082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p569>}

(lldb) po testID
0xd0000000055c0082 <x-coredata://CEB1EDA5-7F7A-4342-85E5-6C2E261308CC/Foo/p343>

(lldb) p testID.isTemporaryID
(bool) $7 = false

(lldb) p obj
(NSManagedObject *) $9 = 0x000000010f338630

(lldb) po results
<__NSArrayI 0x10f205c70>(

)

(lldb) po testID.entity
 nil
```

The `nil` `entity` on the `testID` is strange, but I'm not sure that's "bad."

So, I'm obviously at a loss as to why the fetch is coming back empty. The entity name is correct, the fetch and predicate look good, and the object is in the context, but still zero results.

**Additional Context:**

Essentially, the larger picture is that I have a background operation which uses its own Managed Object Context (MOC) to perform some work. The results of that work are needed on the main queue, so I package up the objectIDs resulting from the work and pass those to the main queue. On the main queue I need the actual managed objects back, so I'm trying to fetch them, by objectID, from the main queue's MOC. I realize I can use `objectWithID:` or `existingObjectWithID:error:` or even `objectRegisteredForID:` on the MOC to get these objects, but each have their own special issues:

- `objectWithID:` might return an object which is bogus if the object is not in the context, and if it is in the context it will return a fault.
- `existingObjectWithID:error:` is great, since we'll get back `nil` (rather than a bogus object) but it too returns a fault.
- `objectRegisteredForID:` will return `nil` if the object is not in the context already.

So, if I use either `objectWithID:` or `existingObjectWithID:error:` in a loop to get a bunch of objects, that's potentially `n` trips to the persisted store to fault the objects, meaning performance is going to be potentially awful. If I use `objectRegisteredForID:` I might not get the object at all if it happens to not already be in the main queue's MOC.

So, rather than try to iterate over the array, I expected a fetch request would limit the overhead of interacting with the persistance store and return all the objects I needed in one fell swoop.

**Addition:**

As an aside, the issue really feels like it has to do with the `@"self IN %@"` predicate, since I can remove that predicate and fetch all objects of `entityName` without issue. I have also tried `@"objectID IN %@"` as the predicate with the same (zero) results.

Comment: Your object does not look like a proper object. The nil `entity` is a clue: there is something fishy about your object IDs. Your posted code looks fine. Is the `Foo` entity correct?

Comment: @Mundi What makes you think the object is not correct? I didn't supply a po of obj since it actually prints the object and that's sharing too much info here. "Foo" is not the real entity name either, but Foo was substituted using a search and replace (only the names have been changed to protect IP). Thanks.

Comment: The fact that the `entity` attribute is nil is extremely suspicious. I'm not sure what would cause that, but it makes the ID objects suspect of being bogus or broken in some way.

Comment: It's a tradeoff. If you think you cannot share any pertinent information it lowers the probability of a fix. I have told you the reason why I think your object is not correct, and so has @Tom. - People steal valuable ideas on Stackoverflow all the time - better be careful.

Comment: @Mundi Sorry, I thought my writeup included all pertinent information, and I must have misunderstood your comment... perhaps I should have read it: "Your object[ID] does not look like a proper object[ID]" which makes much more sense to me.

Comment: So Apple say share objects between contexts by using their objectID, except you can't! Funny. At least we have a work around to use objectWithID on the background context first to get a faulted object then can perform efficient fetches of data using that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, so ready for a trip down the Core Data rabbit hole?

**TL;DR**

`NSManagedObjectID`s whose persistent store coordinator is no longer in memory lose their `NSEntityDescription` (`entity`) and do not equate (`isEqual:` returns `NO`) to `NSManagedObjectID`s from a different persistent store coordinator even though their `URIRepresentation` is the same.

**Down the Rabbit Hole**

Sweet... here we go.

Remember, I'm gathering the array of objectIDs from a separate Managed Object Context (MOC) on a separate thread? Good. I didn't mention, however, that that MOC is using its own Persistent Store Coordinator (PSC) (pointing at the same file, of course). That PSC and MOC are short lived since once the work is done they are autoreleased, but while they are alive, I save off instances of `NSManagedObjectID` into an `NSArray` (which gets passed to a different thread).

Once received in the separate thread, the `NSManagedObjectID`s have a `nil` entity. This seems to be happening (educated guess here...) because the PSC from which these objectIDs came from is now no longer in memory and the `NSManagedObjectID` must keep a week reference to the `NSEntityDescription` (`entity`) which must be held by the PSC. The `nil` `entity` seems to cause issues, as commenters suspected...

I can't be sure of the internals, but it would appear that without the `entity` the `NSManagedObjectID` is **not** equal to another `NSManagedObjectID` with the same `URIRepresentation`. Let me illustrate:

In the following code:
* `objectID` is an `NSManagedObjectID *` from a persistant store which is no longer in memory and whose entity property is `nil`.
* `managedObjectContext` is our MOC on our current thread (of course)

```
NSURL *URIRep = objectID.URIRepresentation;
NSManagedObjectID *newObjectID = [managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:URIRep];
```

If we look at this in the debugger... guess what:

```
(lldb) p [ojectID isEqual:newObjectID]
(bool) $0 = false
```

Even though the `URIRepresentation` of these two objectIDs *must* be the same, the objects do not equate.

This is almost certainly why the predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", objectIDs]` is failing to match any objects and causing the fetch request to return zero objects.

Interestingly, however, in the following code, where `testID` is an `NSManagedObjectID *` from a persistant store which is no longer in memory and whose entity property is `nil`, the object is retrieved from the MOC without issue:

```
NSManagedObject *obj = [managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:testID error:&error];
```

**Workaround**

There are two things which I've verified as a workaround for this:

1. Use the same Persistent Store Coordinator (PSC) when communicating `NSManagedObjectID`s between contexts (and make sure it stays resident in memory). If this is done, the `NSManagedObjectID`s never lose their `entity` and everything works as expected.
2. Instead of passing `NSManagedObjectID`s around from context to context, use their `URIRepresentation`. i.e. instead of passing an array of `NSManagedObjectID` objects, pass an array of `NSURL`s representing the `URIRepresentation` of each `NSManagedObjectID`. Once ready to perform a fetch with those objectIDs use the `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:` message to get a `NSManagedObjectID` from the current MOC's PSC.

Option 1 is simpler, but might have some disadvantages with concurrency timing and may be too restrictive if, say, you wanted to have a separate PSC for your operations which was read only, for instance.

In my (relatively limited) experience calling `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:` it appears to be very performant, so converting `URIRepresentation` `NSURL`s to `NSManagedObjectID`s doesn't seem to add that much overhead.

**Thanks**

Thanks for following along... I hope this helps explain the issue and workarounds clearly. I certainly feel like I earned a merit badge in Core Data object IDs and persistent store coordinators by digging through all this.

Cheers,

Levi

Comment: Very interesting. I suggest filing a bug about the object IDs failing to match, because they really should. Based on your results I suspect that `existingObjectWithID` actually parses the URI representation, making other attribute values irrelevant. If **that** works, your fetch predicate should have worked, and `isEqual:` should return `YES`. [I filed a similar bug a while ago but in my case it was specifically iCloud related.]

Comment: I'd like to suggest another workaround, first do objectWithID then use that object in the predicate. Now we can take advantage of Decreasing Fault Overhead, Batch Faulting and Prefetching in the background context.