# NSConcurrencyType for using independent NSManagedObjectContexts on the same queue

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data

In a CoreData based app, I process an import via a background `NSOperation`. Because the operation is running on an operation queue, I utilize the legacy `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` to work with the `NSManagedObjectContext`. During this import operation, I also access a `NSManagedObjectContext` of a secondary database. As it is running on the operation queue, it also uses the thread confinement concurrency type. This has worked great for years, but `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is now deprecated in iOS 9.

It appears that my only (non-deprecated) option is to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, perform the import in a `performBlock:` for the primary context, and wrap every call to the secondary context or `NSManagedObject`s from the secondary context in a `performBlockAndWait:`.  In addition, I have to take extreme care not to touch an object from the other context on the wrong queue.

This line:

```
primaryObject.attribute = secondaryObject.attribute;
```

Changes to something like this:

```
id secondaryObjectAttributeValue = nil;

[secondaryContext performBlockAndWait:^{
   secondaryObjectAttributeValue = secondaryObject.attribute;
}];

primaryObject.attribute = secondaryObjectAttributeValue;
```

Does anyone have a better option for working with multiple `NSManagedObjectContext`s on the same queue, without using `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` or jumping through these tedious `performBlock:` hoops?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a private queue context but to alter your approach a little bit:

1. Create your `NSOperation` subclass
2. In the `main` create the private context
3. Execute a block on that private context in the main
4. In the block call the methods that handle the actual import
5. Save the context in that same block
6. Exit the block
7. Exit the operation.

Basically your code should be the same as before just wrapped in a `-performBlock:` inside of the `-main` method of the `NSOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern here is to pass the objectID of the object in the main context object to the NSOperation, either via init or a property. Then in the main method of the operation create the background context, and then inside a performBlock load the object into the background context using the objectID property, achieved using the method existingObjectWithID.

When you save the background context, merge the changes back into the main context either manually using the notification and merge method, or automatically with this setting in your app delegate:

```
self.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;
```

Note: When using this pattern [be wary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965913/259521) of using the objectID in any other way, like a fetch for example.